# What is Exact Use of backend_model and source_model node in System.xml in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Magento.

I found many time `<source_model>` and `<backend_model>` node in system.xml file.

I know for many different purpose we can define our own code in Model file. But anyone can please describe nice and brief solution for use of both of this node and its purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<source_model/>**

The <source_model/> tag specifies a Model class (in URI/Grouped Class Name format) to populate a field’s default options. As of Magento, it works with selects and multi-selects.

**<backend_model>**

Once a form is submitted to Magento, its values must be saved. For System Configuration fields, this is normally handeled with the Model class

```
Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
```

However, there may be times where you want your System Configuration to use a different backend model. The <backend_model/> tag allows you to specify a different Model class (using URI/Grouped Class Name format).